# How to insert date into sql server through dateTimePicker in windows forms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, datetime

I have a form in windows forms application that contains an identification date field. The form should insert this date among other fields to a table in the sql server db

The column where the date should be stored is of datetime type.

My problem is that I recieve an exception when trying to perform insertion operation.

**Date is stored in the database in this format : 2013-01-01 00:00:00.000**

I tried to change the format of the date picker to be **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss** to match the format of data in the database but I still getting that exception. I even tried to use a text box instead of a date picker but I can't get rid of the exception.

My application is using Entity Framework 6 to connect to the database.

## Update 1 :

Here is the model class :

```
public partial class Material
{
    public Material()
    {
        this.ItemMaterials = new HashSet<ItemMaterial>();
    }

    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime IdentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemMaterial> ItemMaterials { get; set; }
}
```

I'm also depending on the control explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms) to handle CRUD Operations.

The exception gives me this message :

{"The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Stack Trace :

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()

Comment: You haven't shown any of your code, which makes it hard to know what's wrong with it...

Comment: Use the DateTime value of the date picker, not the formatted value.

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact , there isn't much code to show because saving and adding is handled through this control that was created to handle binding between forms and EF
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms

This is how the form looks like after adding the control
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcxkspg9fiyqhqw/form.png?dl=0

Comment: Well you could at least show us the model class...

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated the question with model class.

I'm doing the binding stuff through the advanced databinding dialog inside properties

here is a screenshot 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvxu0xlifj4lkla/binding.png?dl=0

Comment: @GertArnold I've tried it without the custom format but there is no difference.

Comment: `DateTimePicker.Value`!

Comment: So have you used a debugger to find out what the value of `IdentDate` is at the point where it's failing?

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet , when I rechecked the value in the debugger I could figure that there may be a difference in the format :)

Comment: The format should be completely irrelevant. Your model uses  a DateTime, not a string - there should be no text representation involved at all.

Comment: I will try to investigate more to understand what is going on.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right ! It was just a sort of luck , it only worked one time but the exception returned again !

Answer (score 1):

That exception typically occurs when a `DateTime` property is set to `DateTime.MinValue` (1/1/0001). Be sure to debug and check to make sure that any and all `DateTime` properties (even nullable ones) are not set to `DateTime.MinValue`. Be sure to check your `Material` object as well as any child objects as well.

Why it throws that exception is because EF maps C#'s `DateTime` to SQL's `datetime` type, which would normally be ok, except that C#'s `DateTime` can use dates that `datetime` can't (but SQL's `datetime2` can). When you try to save a `DateTime` with a value not supported by SQL's `datetime` it thinks that you're trying to save a `datetime2` value into a column currently specified as a `datetime`.

Documentation:

[datetime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

[datetime2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)